# IBM BPM 8,5.6 A way to traverse the activities in a process

Tags: javascript, ibm-bpm

I have been assigned to a project to translate various texts in quite large IBM BPM processes (large numbers of coaches with literals text and activities with JavaScript content eg. setting error-messages). Therefore I would like to "extract" all contents of a given Process App in a structured manner. The different processes, their activities, the Javascript, the text-literals they contain etc.

I have found out, that I can export a process, but the twx-file does seem to be IBM-internal format only. One cannot even find a literal text inside the file.

I have read about the JavaScript types like TWProcess, TWTask etc. and from their description it seems it should be possible, but I cannot get it to work. Eg the

```
tw.system.model.findProcessByName(<a name>).steps
```

returns

```
"No variable type found for type name: Step".
```

Using

```
tw.system.model.findProcessByName(<a name>).name
```

works fine and returns the expected name.

Does anyone have a piece of JavaScript that could traverse the definition of processes in an IBM BPM Process App? Or is the JavaScript in IBM BPM only for controlling the activities and show status and content of *running* processes?

Answer (score 0):

The .twx file is actually simply a zip file of what amount to XML files.  You can parse them if you really need to, but doing so is fairly complex.  We have written code to do this for static code analysis of IBM BPM solutions.  [Neches](https://neches.bp-3cloud.com) is our static code analysis tool for IBM BPM that parses this data into a custom data schema to allow us to do analysis across BPM solutions.  I believe we either have the data you need there or can get it.

In the interest of sharing, the data you want will likely be either the coach files or the coach view files.  These can be identified as they coaches file names will be 2025.*some guid*.xml and coach view will be 64.*some guid*.xml

Our company can help answer this question if you are interested.